# Some strings have completely disappeared from Transifex

Tags: support, bug, localization, transifex

Recently I posted already two related bug reports about Transifex issues:

1. [Already translated strings have lost their translations](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/306091/339911)
2. [Translations are not used from Transifex for localized sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/306244/339911)

Now I noticed that some strings that are still used on localized sites in correct translated forms have completely disappeared from Transifex. I.e. I can't find the source string by translation text or even by original (English) text.

This issue is different from the above two, but I think the root of issue is the same.

Many of last [ruSO.meta](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/) reports are about translation problems that happened recently. Before the current issue we could fix them locally (by editing translations in Transifex). However this is not productive because we did the same work (restore the lost translations) many times. Now we can't fix it, because the original strings are gone from Transifex.

Comment: Huh. That's weird. I pinged Samo, he'll take a look. Do you have an example of the strings you can't find anymore? (Feel free to just link me to some example reports on SOru's meta, too.)

Comment: @AdamLear for instance, many strings from [this](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/badges/get/events) page. Nicolas says that he did translation for that page via Transifex recently.

Comment: e.g. [this one](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/132800164) was removed and then added again (can tell by the suggestion which is a 100% match), seems to fit the culprit of random strings disappearing

Comment: @m0sa I know you mean "Not a Robot" (which I believe g3rv4 modified due to [a request](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1665/127) on SOes). But I think Transifex generates different IDs for each project (language / site). For future references, could you please include the key? Something like [this](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-es/translate/#es/english/132799565?key=557602e46ca673366a2e1469d556c02f) would do.

Comment: @m0sa currently the site is is still out of sync with Transifex state. E.i. translations on the site don’t exist in Transifex (see my comment above). Did you actually finish this issue?