# "Added 1 comments" in moderator flag queue

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-tools, plurals

A picture with freehand circle says more than a thousand [wordS](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/63791/295232):

[image]

<sub>(names have been covered to protect the innocent)</sub>

Comment: I hope you're prepared for one of the SE staff to come round your door armed with a giant S.

Comment: `if( n>1): "comments"; else: "comment"`... perhaps a pet peeve of some (including me), but if only one text is possible, it makes sense to leave it in plural tense, as it applies for far more cases than when there is only one comment I guess.

Comment: That would work for English, but not e.g. for [ru.SO] where you have 1 комментарий, 2-4 комментария and 5+ комментариев. (Though I'm not sure if the moderator tools have been translated into Russian.)

Comment: @Glorfindel all (ok, most of) moderator pages are translatable via Transifex. But now there are [weird issues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/306656/339911) with translations.

Comment: BTW, plurals in Russian are slightly harder: one (1, 21, 31...) “комментарий”, two (2-4, 22-24, 32-34...) “комментария”, many (5-20, 25-30, 35-40...) “комментариев”.

Comment: @alexolut я знаю.

Comment: It's just very unlikely that someone would add 5 or more comments to a question while flagging it...

Comment: [Насколько хорошо?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bn01M.jpg)

Comment: Cyrillic handwriting (and italic) is still hard for me.

Comment: @alexolut Next time the CEO emeritus of Stack Exchange would have to bring more troubles, a *Й*, a *Я*, and a pair of *ЕВ*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At some time in the distant past the translation string was properly pluralized.

[image]